# How can I increment month number if given day is last day of current month?

Tags: python, datetime, calendar

I'am building a Weather Forecast Web Scraper in Python. I have a little problem with dates. I have days for forecast in list like that `[29,30,31,1,2,3]`. I need to format that to date format like **2019-08-29**, but I don't know how to increment month if it's last day of current month.

I've tried to join current month to my days, but if I join it I have all dates with that month like:
`[2019-08-29, 2019-08-30, 2019-08-31,2019-08-01,2019-08-02,2019-08-03]` instead `[2019-08-29, 2019-08-30, 2019-08-31,2019-09-01,2019-09-02,2019-09-03]`.

So I need Your help to check in loop if day is last day of current month then increment month.

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt
from calendar import monthrange

days = [29,30,31,1,2,3,4]
cy = int(dt.datetime.today().year)
cm = int(dt.datetime.today().month)
last_day = monthrange(cy,cm)[1]



for i,day in enumerate(days):
    while (days[i] - days[i+1]) == -1:
        i+=1
        print(cm)
    if (days[i] - days[i+1]) != -1:
        print(cm)
        cm += 1
    print(cm)
```

Comment: `days[i+1]` will get an error when you get to the last element of `days`.

Comment: What do you want to do exactly?

Comment: Why not do date arithmetic and then getting the month of the date, rather than dealing with day numbers?

Comment: Otherwise you also have to remember to increment year if you go past 12-31.

Comment: why not just work with `date`/`datetime` objects and do calculations with `timedelta`? Or even use some of the third-party packages that work with dates? Probably can use also some of the convenient functions in the `calendar` module to iterate over days in the week/month.

Comment: I know that ```days[i+1]``` get an error but i don't know how to handle that :(

Comment: @buran Can You explain how can I do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using builtin datetime module

```
from datetime import date, timedelta
day0 = date.today()
for td in range(7):
    myday = day0 + timedelta(days=td)
    print(myday.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
```

output

```
2019-08-30
2019-08-31
2019-09-01
2019-09-02
2019-09-03
2019-09-04
2019-09-05
```

two alternatives using third-party [pendulum](https://pendulum.eustace.io/), but you can use any of other popular third-party packages too

```
import pendulum
d0 = pendulum.now()
dates = [d0.add(days=d).strftime('%Y-%m-%d') for d in range(7)]
print(dates)

start = pendulum.now()
end = start.add(days=6)
for d in pendulum.period(start, end):
    print(d.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
```

output

```
['2019-08-30', '2019-08-31', '2019-09-01', '2019-09-02', '2019-09-03', '2019-09-04', '2019-09-05']
2019-08-30
2019-08-31
2019-09-01
2019-09-02
2019-09-03
2019-09-04
2019-09-05
```

Answer (score 0):

So if all you are trying to do is have a for loop that increments the month, then this should work:

```
days = [29, 30, 31, 1, 2, 3, 4]
cy = int(dt.datetime.today().year)
cm = int(dt.datetime.today().month)
last_day = monthrange(cy,cm)[1]

for i, day in enumerate(days):
    last_day = monthrange(cy, cm)[1]
    print(f"{cy}-{cm}-{day}")
    if cm == 12 and day == last_day:
        cy += 1
        cm = 1
    elif day == last_day:
        cm += 1
```

Output:

```
2019-8-29
2019-8-30
2019-8-31
2019-9-1
2019-9-2
2019-9-3
2019-9-4
```

This method is prone to errors though, so you would need to add error handling. For example, if current month is November and you get `31` in days, you'd get incorrect dates for next iteration (`2019-11-30, 2019-12-31, 2020-1-1`). This only works if `days` is correct and won't have any errors.

Like others suggested, it is probably safer to some preprocessing beforehand and then calculate a range of dates altogether.